# How to get last (n) dates by sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For example `DECLARE @a = 10;`

Required output be like:

```
1) 16/5/2020
2) 15/5/2020
3) 14/5/2020
4) 13/5/2020
5) 12/5/2020
6) 11/5/2020
7) 10/5/2020
8) 9/5/2020
9) 8/5/2020
10) 7/5/2020
```

If `Declare @b = 5` then get last five days of dates in output.

Comment: `select top (@a)`?

Comment: Welcome to SO - please read the FAQ and guides to asking a good question.

Comment: Learn to think in sets. Imagine you have a table of sequential numbers. When you select rows from that table using `datediff (day, x, <somedate>)` you get a series of sequential dates that start or end with <somedate>. A table of numbers (dynamically generated or static) is incredibly useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -SEQ4(), CURRENT_DATE()) AS generated_date
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>10)) 
ORDER BY generated_date desc;
```

> SEQn() functions are not guaranteed to be gap free, so you need to use ROW_NUMBER()

```
WITH tally AS (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SEQ4()) AS rn
   FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>10))
)
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -rn, CURRENT_DATE()) AS generated_date
FROM tally
ORDER BY generated_date
```

Comment: fyi, SEQn() functions are not guaranteed to be gap free, so you need to use ROW_NUMBER()